# Read Many Small Files Sequentially

Tags: bash

I have a large amount (4000) of rather small files - on average maybe 3 lines (and several collections of this kind). The alphabetic order of the file names corresponds to the expected order for reading.

Essentially what I would like to do is skim their content quickly in sequential order, essentially:

```
cat * | less
```

The problem with this command is that I do not see where a file ends and a new one begins.

I would also like to note that I know that I can append a mark to the end of each file and then combine them. My question is aiming at a solution which does not require changing the files or creating new files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A little loop on the prompt should do the trick: simply use `find` (or `ls`) to get all the file names you need. Pipe those to the `while read`, giving the variable name, and then `echo` the marker and then `cat` the file. `done` ends the loop. Pipe the resulting stream to `less` and you should easily be able to skim the whole thing.

```
find . -type f | sort | while read file; do echo "#### $file" ; cat $file; done | less
```

Comment: I like this solution b/c for optical reasons it is preferrable to choose the separator

Comment: What would have to be changed about this command to make it work in fish bash?

Comment: @Raffael The command should work on plain-old bash and most compatible shells. I just tried it on fish (which I never used before): it seems to get confused because of the loop, as if it does not capture the end of the statement at `done` correctly ... don't know how to make it work, though.

Comment: injected `sort` between `find` and the loop b/c as I just realized (after short confusion) `find` does not pre-sort its results (which makes sense of course)

Answer (score 3):

```
tail -n +1 * | less
```

Looks like this:

```
==> txts/18091.pdf-000_p01_p1_p01.png.txt <==
Deutscher Bundestag


==> txts/18091.pdf-000_p02_p1_p01.png.txt <==
Stenografischer Bericht


==> txts/18091.pdf-000_p03_p1_p01.png.txt <==
91. Sitzung


==> txts/18091.pdf-000_p04_p1_p01.png.txt <==
Berlin, Donnerstag, den 5. März 2015
```

Answer (score 1):

If you, a human being, want to skim the contents of lots of files sequentially, just do

```
less *
```

When you're done scanning one file, use `:n` to open the next.

Comment: +1 - though ":n"-ing thousands of times is a bit inconvient. Also I would like to see the content next to each other.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `find` without a loop (checked with GNU find 4.4.2):

```
find -type f -printf "--< %f >----\n" -exec cat {} \; | less
```

This is independent of any shell peculiarities (as long as you are using GNU find) and adds a nice header too:

```
--< x >----
hello
--< y >----
world
```